Playwright select dynamic element inside form
I'm using Playwright to interact with a webpage containing a form, you can find the full form's HTML code here.
The element of interest is the following:
<div class="form-ajax-success alert alert-success">
    <p>The form has successfully been sent. We will contact you as soon as possible.</p>
</div>

After correctly filling the form and clicking the button to submit it, it becomes:
<div class="form-ajax-success alert alert-success" style="display: block;">
    <p>The form has successfully been sent. We will contact you as soon as possible.</p>
</div>

The effect on the page is that it shows the success message at the beginning of the form. I would like to check if the message is displayed after I fill in the form.
I tried with this code:
if page.locator('.form-ajax-success').is_visible():
    print("Message sent")

But the check always fails, even when the message is shown on the page. How can I check if the form was correctly submitted, using the Python version of Playwright?
Thank you for your help.
EDIT: I also tryied with if page.locator('div.form-ajax-success').is_visible():, but same result.

What is the error?

@VishalAggarwal I mean that page.locator('.form-ajax-success').is_visible() always returns False, even when I see the message on screen.

Please post a [mcve] with the page under automation/test and the full, runnable code, not a pastebin link. Thanks!

If visibility doesn't work properly, wait for the attribute with to_have_attribute
locator = page.locator(".form-ajax-success")
expect(locator).to_have_attribute("style", "display: block;")

await expect(page.locator(".form-ajax-success")).toHaveAttribute("style", "display: block;");


Turns out that actually, my locator isn't able to select that element to start with, so I need some more fiddling with this. But thanks for pointing me to this other way!

This proved to be useful in one of my test scenarios.Thanks!

I think locator is incorrect as the full class name is not provided.You may use a little regex here:
if page.locator('div[class^="form-ajax-success"]').is_visible():

